# Issue with timepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, timepicker

I have used timepicker in my project but its not working properly.It gave me Uncaught Type Error.

When i click on textbox i need such output

[image]

I tried using timepicker in this way  :

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css">
<title>TimePicker</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Time Picker</h2>
  <p>This example of time picker using bootstrap and jquery.</p>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="starttime">Start Time:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starttime" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="endtime">End Time:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtitme" readonly>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
$(".starttime").clockpicker({
  twelvehour: true,
});
$("#endtitme").clockpicker({
  twelvehour: true,
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing `clock js` in your code

add `clock js` and its work and also change `.starttime` to `#starttime` because its id in your field not class

```
<script src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$("#starttime").clockpicker({
  twelvehour: true,
  autoclose: true
});
$("#endtitme").clockpicker({
  twelvehour: true,
  autoclose: true 
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css">
  <script src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
  <title>TimePicker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Time Picker</h2>
    <p>This example of time picker using bootstrap and jquery.</p>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starttime">Start Time:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starttime" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="endtime">End Time:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtitme" readonly>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

add `autoclose: true` in your clockpicker

Comment: Thank you for replay but after select time clock is not automatically close.

Comment: add `autoclose: true` in `clockpicker`

Comment: Thank you @Bhargav Chudasama for help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should add clockpicker library, but you only added stylesheet. Add `http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js` this before `...bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css` line

Answer (score 1):

Try it in document.ready.

also you don't have element having class 'starttime'
change .starrttime to #starttime

```
    <title>TimePicker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Time Picker</h2>
      <p>This example of time picker using bootstrap and jquery.</p>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="starttime">Start Time:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starttime" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endtime">End Time:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtitme" readonly>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#starttime").clockpicker({
          twelvehour: true,
        });

        $("#endtitme").clockpicker({
          twelvehour: true,
       });  
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if it still doesn't work
put 'clockpicker' class in div tag.

```
        <div class="form-group clockpicker">
          <label for="starttime">Start Time:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starttime" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clockpicker">
          <label for="endtime">End Time:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtitme" readonly>
        </div>
```